# Django urls giving 404 error

Tags: python, django, url, urlconf

Django is giving me a 404 error whenever I try to access "blog/" on my site, but I've defined the URLs I want and they should be matching that.

Main urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mySiteProject.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

blog.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index')
)
```

404 page:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/blog/

Using the URLconf defined in mySiteProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/

The current URL, blog/, didn't match any of these.
```

Site structure:

```
mySiteProject
    blog
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
        urls.py
        __init__.py
    mySiteProject
        wsgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        __init__.py
    manage.py
    db.sqlite3
```

Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'blog'
)
```

Comment: Is your file called blog.urls.py? Could you please share how different source files are organized in your project i.e., directory structure of your project?

Comment: A stupid question: Have you saved your edits in your main *urls.py*? It doesn't seem like your server has registered the change, given your error message.

Comment: @shaktimaan: Yes, it is. I'll update the post with the different files.

Comment: @SteinarLima: Yes, I've saved. Whenever I go to a different URL, it shows "blog/" as being tried.

Comment: What is defined in your INSTALLED_APPS setting?

Comment: Are you using runserver for testing? I'm inclined to agree with @SteinarLima and it doesn't look like your changes are taking effect. Try stopping the server and starting it again to force a recompile.

Comment: @schillingt: Yes. I've tried restarting a few times; I'll try once more. Edit; still nothing. This is baffling me.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `patterns` requires a prefix as its first argument followed by zero or more arguments. So I believe `urlpatterns = patterns(url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'))` in `blog.urls.py` should look like this: `urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`patterns` requires a prefix as its first argument followed by zero or more arguments. So this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'))  # won't work
```

in `blog.urls.py` should look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'))  # now has a prefix as first argument
```

In its present state, the `patterns` function in `blog.urls.py` will return an empty `pattern_list`, which means that `url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))` will return no patterns.